# d3 - Bar Chart overlapping my text, how can I reduce the domain so it doesn't?

Tags: d3.js

```js
const bar3 = d3.select('#bar3').append('svg').attr('width', 800).attr('height', 225);


var bar1Data = [{
    position: 1,
    label: '70k',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 200
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 300
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 100
  },
];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#FFC828", "#FFAC27", '#FF8F26', '#FF7125']);

const max = d3.sum(bar1Data, d => d.value)
console.log(max)

const maximum = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bar1Data, d => d.value)])
  .range([200, 0])



//Join data to rects

const rects = bar3.selectAll('rect')
  .data(bar1Data)

rects
  .attr('width', 196)
  .attr('height', d => 225 - maximum(d.value))
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', 0)

rects.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 196)
  .attr('height', d => 225 - maximum(d.value))
  .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 199)
  .attr('y', d => maximum(d.value))
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i));

function sum(array, start, end) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) total += array[i];
  return total;
}


bar3.append("text")
  .attr("x", (400))
  .attr("y", 80)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style('font-family', 'marsBook')
  .style("font-size", "24px")
  .text("Generation of Head of Household")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="bars">
  <div id="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Hi,

I am struggling to get my bar chart to be lower than the text field. I'm not sure what I've done, but the chart keeps overlapping the title and I'd like that to not be the case. Preferably, keeping all things in the `#bar3` container and lowering the domain. But it hasn't seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change not the domain (which is the set of values the data can take), but the range. Specifically, the 200 in `maximum` denotes 200 pixels from the top, and `0` denotes the very top. So changing that fixes it:

```js
const bar3 = d3.select('#bar3').append('svg').attr('width', 800).attr('height', 225);


var bar1Data = [{
    position: 1,
    label: '70k',
    value: 100
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 200
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 300
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    label: '71K - 149K',
    value: 100
  },
];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#FFC828", "#FFAC27", '#FF8F26', '#FF7125']);

const max = d3.sum(bar1Data, d => d.value)
console.log(max)

const maximum = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bar1Data, d => d.value)])
  .range([200, 50])

//Join data to rects

const rects = bar3.selectAll('rect')
  .data(bar1Data)

rects
  .attr('width', 196)
  .attr('height', d => 225 - maximum(d.value))
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', 0)

rects.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 196)
  .attr('height', d => 225 - maximum(d.value))
  .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 199)
  .attr('y', d => maximum(d.value))
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i));

function sum(array, start, end) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) total += array[i];
  return total;
}

bar3.append("text")
  .attr("x", 400)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style('font-family', 'marsBook')
  .style("font-size", "24px")
  .text("Generation of Head of Household")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="bars">
  <div id="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Another option is to plot the bars not directly on the `svg`, but to use a `g`-child element instead, and give that some margin at the top:

```
const barContainer = bar3.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(20, 40)');
```

And then append the bars to the barContainer and the text to the svg. That allows you to use 0 in the range again.